# Call function in sibling file?

Tags: rust

I feel like this is a silly and obvious question. I have two files that depends on eachother like a `friend` might in C++. My current solution is to put all the code into a mega file. How can I use two files instead which call eachother? Here's a reproducible of my problem

main.rs

```
mod file0;
pub fn testA() -> i32 {
    return 2;
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello", file0::test1());
}
```

file0.rs

```
mod main;
pub fn testA() -> i32 {
    return main::testB() + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues with your code here. Firstly, `main.rs` implicitly creates a module at the crate root - so you can remove the `mod main;` line from `file0.rs`. Secondly, the crate's root is accessed via `crate::` when referring to items - so `return main::testB() + 5;` should be `crate::testB() + 5;`. You can also use `super::` to refer to the parent module rather than a potentially long absolute path if you have nested modules, which would be `return super::testB() + 5;`.

Here's a working example:

```
// main.rs
mod file0;
pub fn testB() -> i32 {
  return 2;
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello - {}", file0::testA());
}

// file0.rs
pub fn testA() -> i32 {
  return crate::testB() + 5;
  // alternatively:
  // return super::testB() + 5;
}
```

I've also fixed some other minor issues in this example - the function names weren't consistent and the format string for `println` did not contain any placeholders.